# Gradle .jar dependecies in eclipse with libgdx

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx

How do I build the .jar files included here: https://code.google.com/p/box2d-editor/source/browse/loader-libgdx/src/aurelienribon/bodyeditor/BodyEditorLoader.java?r=6a4430d04ece96a2b22dfde528531fa600776519 in order to use the physics body editor? If I place them inside my libgdx project folder somewhere, will gradle import in eclipse build the sources and resolve the dependencies?

This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: "java"

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]


eclipse.project {
    name = appName + "-core"

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    }
}
```